# Pass DateTime value by AJAX

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

```js
var val2 = $('#range').val();
var val3 = $('#name').val();
var val4 = $('#born').val();
var formData = {
  'range': val2,
  'firstName': val3,
  'bornDate': val4 // Is DateTime value
}
var conData = {
  user: formData
}

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/NilvimAjaxService.aspx/InsertNew",
  data: JSON.stringify(conData),
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data) {},
  error: function(date) {}
});
```

If the date is like: `01/01/2012` it's fine and the call works. However if the date is like: `25/01/2012` then the error is:

> ExceptionType : "System.FormatException" Message : "25/01/2012 is not a valid value for a DateTime."

How can the problem be overcome?

Comment: Sounds like your server is configured to accept MM/DD/YYYY date formats, not the DD/MM/YYYY you're sending. I'd suggest using a format which both can read, perhaps YYYY-MM-DD, or converting the date format before you send the request.

Comment: Ok, I think I got it right. Thanks!